# “Canceling” dx in Derivative Equation

Tags: calculus

So I just hopped into Keisler’s *Infinitesimal Calculus* and I saw a basic method for finding a derivative. I have no issue with his method, but a super elementary issue is stumping me for some reason. He has the following:

dx/dy = (x^2 + 2xdx + (dx)^2 -x^2) / (dx)

And then he preceded to reduce to

2x + dx

Why is there only one dx? I thought it was improper to “cancel” when something is being added as opposed to multiplied as we see here with 2xdx **+** (dx)^2

Comment: $\dfrac{2x dx + (dx)^2}{dx}= \dfrac{2x dx}{dx} + \dfrac{(dx)^2}{dx} = 2x + dx$

Comment: This is not a rigorous computation because $\mathsf dx$ is not a "variable" in the sense that $x$ is.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) by now

Comment: @Math1000 Note the context: Infinitesimal Calculus. $dx$ and $dy$ are in fact variables in this treatment.